# Install CDE on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments

Is it possible that I can I install CDE through apt-get on Ubuntu 14.04 64-Bit? I am really desperate.

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about CDE (a desktop environment developed in 1990th and not widely used anymore) and not KDE? Your user avatar looks like a default background of one of previous versions of KDE.

Answer (score 2):

> CDE - The Common Desktop Environment is X Windows desktop environment
>   that was commonly used on commercial UNIX variants such as Sun
>   Solaris, HP-UX and IBM AIX. Developed between 1993 and 1999, it has
>   now been released under an Open Source licence by The Open Group.

[image]

CDE project has [detailed build instructions](http://sourceforge.net/p/cdesktopenv/wiki/LinuxBuild/) in their wiki.

My understanding is that Linux port of CDE is currently an alpha-quality software and has "quite a few known security vulnerabilities". I'm also not aware of any pre-built .debs or a PPA to install CDE from.

> ...it should be made clear that at the moment there are no
>   pre-compiled binaries available for systems so at the moment all will
>   have to be confident enough to compile from source

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear to be packaged in the Ubuntu archives or in any PPAs, so you will need to build it from source, or create a PPA and package it yourself, to be able to install it, currently.

Answer (score 1):

You can apt-get install the package cde-desktop from the Sparky Linux repository, Sparky linux is a derivative of Debian so it should work with some tweaking

Comment: Can you post more information on how to do that? maybe a PPA link?

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh Sorry for the late response but you can find instructions on setting up the repo [here](https://sparkylinux.org/sparky-repository/)